# How can I increment a variable using a loop while using another loop at the same time?

Tags: c, loops

I need to use `j` as a counter and increment it at the same time the `i` increments. This code just keep on giving me random number for `j`.

```
    int i, j;   // counters
    for (i=0, j=1; i<=LENGTH; i++, j++)
    {
        printf("Player %i "\n", j);
        printf("Name:\t");
        fgets(name[i], MAXLENGTH, stdin);
        ...
```

Comment: you only need one variable... here, ignoring the fact you are using the `,` operator, you basically want to have j = i+1 at all times

Comment: Additionally, this code definitely looks like it should work.

Comment: Where is the other loop?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @Bathsheba: huh? `i = 0, j = 1` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I think you're wrong: `for (i = 0, j = 1, k = 2; i < 10; i++, j++, k++)` does exactly what one might expect.

Comment: @Everyone! [My previous comment (now removed) implied you can't initialise more than one variable in a for loop using comma.] Yes indeed I am incorrect but I'll leave this here otherwise nothing else here will make sense. It's declaration together with definition that you can't do with two variables in a for loop using comma. Apologies.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("Player %i "\n", j);
```

Statement consists of two double quotes.

```
printf("Player %i \n", j);
```

or

```
printf("Player %d \n", j);
```

try this code:

```
#define LENGTH 10
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i, j;//counters
    for (i=0, j=1; i<=LENGTH; i++, j++)
    {
        printf("Player j=%i  i=%d \n", j,i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
  int i;//counter
  for (i=0; i<=LENGTH; i++)
  {
      printf("Player %i \n", i + 1);
      printf("Name:\t");
      fgets(name[i], MAXLENGTH, stdin);
  ...
```

Comment: Agreed, though you missed the double quotes before the newline in the first `printf` call. The real question is how did it compile with that going on? ;-)

Comment: The real question is : is is really necessary to compile a code like that? :p

Comment: I hope not, else every C compiler I have worked with gets it wrong by indicating an error. ^_^

Comment: Well, as the question was about i and j, I didn't feel the need to compile a simple printf ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what `name` is, but if it is simply a string, like:

```
char name[MAXLENGTH];
```

then `fgets` will write into the `name` string starting at the `i`th element.  It is possible you are writing past the end of the `name` string.  If `name` is defined locally just before your loop, then you could overwriting both `i` and `j` with "random" data (i.e. you are performing the namesake of this site).

If this is the case, then you should instead call `fgets` as follows:

```
fgets(name, MAXLENGTH, stdin);
```